# Error using csvsql utility in csvkit python package on Mac Yosemite

Tags: python, mysql, macos, csv, pip

I am new to python and mysql. I am trying to use the csvsql utility within the csvkit python library on Mac OS X Yosemite to create a table in my mysql database, and to upload the data. When I try to run

```
csvsql --blanks -d "|" -e "utf8" --db mysql://root:mysqlpassword@localhost:3306/MyDBName --table mytablename --insert /Users/victoria/Documents/iWHW/MyCSVFileName.csv
```

I get:

> You don't appear to have the necessary database backend
>   installed for connection string you're trying to use. Available
>   backends include:
>
> Postgresql:   pip install psycopg2 MySQL:     pip install MySQL-python
>
> For details on connection strings and other backends, please see the
>   SQLAlchemy documentation on dialects at:
>
> http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dialects/

The problem is that I have installed MYSQL-python using pip and it installed correctly. I am having trouble figuring why this error persists. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I resolved it:
Make sure that you have only 1 install of MySQL on your path. I had 2 installs of MySQL server, one through brew and the other manually, and the /usr/local/bin/mysql was pointing to the wrong version.
I updated the symlink to my working mysql version, and the error went away.

Comment: FWIW, I checked and found only one install of mysql server via Brew but am still getting the error.

Comment: Try uninstalling MySQL server (installed via brew),  and install manually. See if that works

Answer (score 0):

On OSX 11.1

```
pip3 install csvkit

pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Then import:

csvsql --db mysql+mysqldb://USERNAME:PASSWD@DBHOST:3306/dbname --tables TABLENAME --insert MY_DATAFILE.cvs